# What are the rules of connecting two adverbs?

Tags: adverbs

Slowly but surely, quickly and precisely, etc. You get the idea.

Some people say that "slowly but surely" is "ゆっくり**と**着実に", others "ゆっくり**だが**しかし着実に"

So which is it? Are there other connective particles I can use, and can I use them with all kinds of adverbials or just with simple adverbs?

Comment: In case you are thinking the と in ゆっくりと着実に is a connective (which だが is), I doubt it is. It's the grammatically optional particle と that comes after adverbs, as in ゆっくり（と）進む.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but ゆっくりと確実に is a simple combination of two adverbs, whereas ゆっくりだがしかし着実に makes a strong contrast between the two, like "slowly, and yet surely". Which you need depends on the context.

Other options:

- ゆっくりそして確実に
- ゆっくりかつ確実に
- ゆっくりながら確実に (relatively literary)

These feel somewhere between "slowly and surely" and "slowly yet surely".